# How to parse data from jason and populate in REST Url

Tags: karate

I can't provide data from json file to Rest URL in karate. My feature file structure is as below; Please help out.

Scenario Outline: Get response

Given def data = read('classpath:JsonFilePath/data.json')

And def data1 = someJson.data[0].data1

And def data2 = someJson.data[0].data2

And path = 'https://myurl/account/#(data1)/phoneno/#(data2)/someoperationname'

When method get

Then status success

In this case, I get invalid account and invalid phoneno error, which means the URL is not getting data from json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Also you have mixed up `url` and `path` refer the docs for this also.

Change to:

```
And url 'https://myurl'
And path 'account', data1, 'phoneno', data2, 'someoperationname'
```

Note how `path` can be comma delimited and variables can be mixed.

I repeat - please read the docs and examples carefully.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the quick response. But actual issue is not solved. I tried with  
 And path 'account', data1, 'phoneno', data2, 'someoperationname'    but not getting proper response. Here data1 and data2 are not data but are variables which have assigned with values that are in json file. I am trying to do data driven testing here. Instead of feeding direct data, i am keeping the same in json file. If using soap request, i can call the json using standard format i.e., #(data) but the same doesn't work in REST path. And the solution you provided works if i hardcode the data.

Comment: @sandeephegde the time has come for me to ask you to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - all the best !